# JSP Model value as key

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I want to use a model value as key to display complete value

for example

country is model attribute in spring.

if country is 'US' then display 'United States'.

if country is 'FR' then display 'France'
....

i need to achieve this with out c:out tag. Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: why don't you use `Map` or `ResourceBundle` for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by [internationalization](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/).
On your messages_en.properties:

```
US=United States
FR=France
ES=Spain
```

and then, on your jsp page call:

```
<spring:message code="${country}" text="${country}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, mine is not locale specific, still whether i can use this approach?. The one i mentioned above is just one example. In some case i use AD as ADMIN, O as OWNER, V as VIEWER.